# how to position elements relatively if they have same z-index value?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div elements. First one is a map. Second one is a search button and the third one is a list of the relative places to be shown if there is an input in the search bar.

So I want to put search bar and the list on top of map elements. I do it with z-index. what I imagine is there is 2 layer first one contains the map and the second one contains the search bar and list so that I have to position them relative to each other.

The map doesn't have a z-index value and z-index values of the search bar and list are 2 and same. Search bar and list show up on top of the map there is no problem here but search bar goes under list. The list when appear doesn't position itself relative to the search bar, although they have same z-index value. So how can I accomplish that the elements that are in the same layer according to their z-index position itself relative to each other? Or shouldn't I use z-index at all? Thanks!

here is mt html code :

```css
.search-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      margin-top: 1vh;
    }

#places{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 96%;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      margin-top: 6vh;
      margin-left: 8px;
    }

 #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60%;
      border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div #map id="map"></div>

<div id="places">
    <ion-item></ion-item>
</div>

<div class="search-container">
<ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
</div>
```

What I want is the list should be shown just below the list and things like margin vs. should be relative to the search bar.

Comment: If you want them relative to each other, put them in a container and put the positioning and z-index on that

Comment: Yeap this is what I just crossed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand all your question, but my code below can be helpful :

```css
.map {
  position: relative;
}

.action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://snazzy-maps-cdn.azureedge.net/assets/127403-no-label-bright-colors.png?v=20171101110035">
  <div class="action">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <div class="list">
      <a href="#1">Location 1</a>
      <a href="#2">Location 1</a>
      <a href="#3">Location 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```